# How to make the nodes visible and make an infinite number of vertices graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I have the following graph:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,minimum size=1cm] (0) at (0,0) {$0$};   
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,minimum size=1cm] (11) at  (-1,0) {$-1$};  
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,minimum size=1cm] (12) at  (-2,0) {$-2$};  
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,minimum size=1cm] (13) at (-3,0) {$-3$}; 
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,minimum size=1cm] (14) at (-4,0) {$-4$}; 
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,minimum size=1cm] (1) at  (1,0) {$1$};  
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,minimum size=1cm] (2) at  (2,0) {$2$};  
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,minimum size=1cm] (3) at (3,0) {$3$}; 
\node[shape=circle,draw=black,minimum size=1cm] (4) at (4,0) {$4$}; 

\draw (0) -- (1);  
\draw (2) -- (1);  
\draw (3) -- (2);  
\draw (4) -- (3); 
\draw (0) --(11);  
\draw (11) -- (12);  
\draw (12) -- (13);  
\draw (13) --(14);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

In this picture, the edges between the nodes are not visible. How to make the edges visible?

Secondly I want the nodes to continue in both direction, i.e. I want the graph to be an infinite graph on both sides. Can someone please help me on how to make the graph infinite?

I would be grateful if someone could fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you can´t see the lines is because your nodes are too big. Change the `minimum size=1cm` to `minimum size=0.5cm` and you will see them.

I do not know what you mean with "make the graph infinite" but here is what I think you might want to achieve: I used a `foreach` loop so you don´t have to copy and paste your code over and over again.

```
\documentclass[border=3.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}
\begin{document} 

$\raisebox{2ex}{$\cdots$}$
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach\x in {-10,...,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,...,10}
    \draw [] (\x,0) circle (1 mm) node[fill=white,draw=black,circle,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=0.8cm] {\x};
     
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}
    \draw[red ] (0,0)
        \foreach \x in {-10,...,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,...,10}
        {-- (\x,0)};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    $\raisebox{2ex}{$\cdots$}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I mean the nodes to continue on both sides, i mean to add \cdots on both sides, for example, suppose the nodes are all integers with $-6$ joined to $-7$, $-7$ joined to $-8$ and so on, is it possible to do it

Comment: @Math_Freak I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it possible to draw the dots from the middle of the node?Also the nodes containing negative coordinates are larger than nodes with positive coordinates, how to fix this?

Comment: In my example I cannot see any difference between negative and positive nodes in size. Their dimensions can be changed with adjusting `inner sep=<value>` and `minimum size=<value>`. I added a possible solution to center the dots to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot  mate,,  +1 for you